# jekyll serve not working without bundle exec

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, jekyll-extensions, jekyll-paginator

I have this `jekyll` project https://github.com/mmistakes/minimal-mistakes

If I run `jekyll serve` this error is displayed.

> WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
>         listen (< 3.1, ~> 3.0) WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs. Please report a bug if this causes problems. Configuration file:
>   /home/kenden/Desktop/minimal-mistakes-master/_config.yml   Dependency
>   Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have jekyll-paginate or one of
>   its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently
>   configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error message
>   from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- jekyll-paginate' If you run
>   into trouble, you can find helpful resources at
>   http://jekyllrb.com/help/!  jekyll 3.1.3 | Error:  jekyll-paginate

I already have `jekyll paginate` installed. I checked using `gem list`. However if I run `bundle exec jekyll serve` then the server starts perfectly.

> Configuration file:
>   /home/kenden/Desktop/minimal-mistakes-master/_config.yml
>               Source: /home/kenden/Desktop/minimal-mistakes-master
>          Destination: /home/kenden/Desktop/minimal-mistakes-master/_site  Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
>         Generating... 
>                       done in 0.104 seconds.  Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/home/kenden/Desktop/minimal-mistakes-master' Configuration file:
>   /home/kenden/Desktop/minimal-mistakes-master/_config.yml
>       Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000   Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.

Why is `jekyll serve` not working and what is difference between `jekyll serve` and `bundle exec jekyll serve` ?

Answer (score 2):

The [Rationale and Purpose of Bundler](http://bundler.io/rationale.html) will probably shed some light on the difference. Most likely you have more than one version of the gem on your system Ruby and it's probably unsure which version to use.

If you don't want to always have to type `bundle exec` read this [article from the Thoughtbot blog](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/but-i-dont-want-to-bundle-exec)

Answer (score 2):

I also met this problem and I solved it by uninstall all the different versions of gems comparing with `Gemfile.lock`.

For example, I found this gem have two different versions: `jekyll-sass-converter (1.4.0, 1.3.0)`. And in `Gemfile.lock`, there is only `jekyll-sass-converter (= 1.3.0)`. So I uninstalled its 1.4.0 version. Then `Jekyll serve` works as expect.

I think the difference between `Jekyll serve` and `bundle exec Jekyll serve` is that `bundle exec` will check the `Gemfile.lock` and use the specific versions of gems in it while `Jekyll serve` somehow confused by the different versions of the same gem.